# Perguntas "respondidas" no Sem resposta

Tags: debate

O que fazer com perguntas em que não há necessidade de resposta?
Por exemplo: no caso de quem fez a pergunta já ter resolvido a questão sem a necessidade de uma resposta de um terceiro ou ele solucionou por meio dos comentários, e sem postar a solução.

A questão é que essas perguntas ficam no menu em `Sem resposta` mesmo já tendo sido resolvidas, o que atrapalha na hora de buscar perguntas antigas sem resposta.

3 exemplos:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11535/comparacao-com-nao-funciona

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11192/jpa-gerando-uma-consulta-estranha-com-nome-de-colunas-estranhas

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9722/executar-funcao-ao-primeiro-acesso-de-uma-pessoa-de-um-site-wordpress

O que fazer nessa situação? Penso podia ter uma opção na votação para fechar esse tipo de pergunta.

Comment: No seu segundo exemplo eu até pedi, via comentários, para o OP postar a solução dele como resposta mas o usuário "sumiu".

Comment: Na segunda pergunta que você listou a resposta do autor é: `O problema estava numa sub-classe que tinha essa coluna mapeada errada`. Será q isso será de utilidade para alguém no futuro? Acho que deveria ser fechada igual a primeira foi.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Se for uma pergunta que pode ter utilidade para outras pessoas, o indicado é deixar um comentário explicando nosso formato de *Pergunta* ***e*** *Resposta*. Depois de alguns dias, se não aconteceu nada, remover a solução de dentro da pergunta (ou copiar o comentário) e publicar uma resposta nós mesmos. Nestes casos, podemos usar o *wiki da comunidade* de modo que não obtemos reputação dessa resposta que não é realmente nossa.

Depois de avisar e não havendo *feedback*, se quiser "roubar" a resposta, é um simples caso de publicar uma resposta sua (não-wiki); expandindo, explicando melhor ou dando mais detalhes. Esse "roubo" faz mais sentido se a solução foi publicada como Comentário e tanto faz se foi o autor da pergunta ou outro usuário. Não publicou resposta porque não quis.
<sub>***Importante***: [citar a origem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8957/201).</sub>

Se a pergunta não tem utilidade para outras pessoas (p.ex.: erro tipográfico no código), ou não tem detalhes suficientes, e o autor dá a entender que resolveu, então seria questão de votar para fechar e votar negativamente se for o caso. Perguntas sem respostas e com *score* negativo terminam sendo deletadas automaticamente.