# Perguntas respondidas mas sem "aceito"

Tags: debate, perguntas

Recentemente notei que tem aparecido muitas perguntas na página inicial do `SO Pt`, perguntas antigas, que já possuem uma resposta, muitas vezes com comentário do próprio autor junto a resposta agradecendo e dizendo que aquilo resolveu o problema, porém a resposta não está marcada como "aceita".

Notei que normalmente isso vem de usuários com pouca reputação e/ou poucas perguntas, o que me faz crer que dificilmente voltarão ao site para dar continuidade.

Nisso vejo 2 "problemas":

- O não ganho de reputação por parte de quem respondeu e resolveu o problema de alguém;
- O constante "reaparecimento" da pergunta na lista principal, pois ela é "editada" automaticamente pela "comunidade" para voltar a receber atenção;

Eu até pesquisei algo relacionado aqui, mas só achei [essa questão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1155/perguntas-respondidas-no-sem-resposta), que está mais relacionada a uma pergunta com a resposta apenas nos comentários.

Gostaria de saber se não há algo que possa ser feito em relação as questões que possuem sim respostas mas que foram deixadas de lado. Algum sistema para sinalizar a questão como "Respondida, porém sem aceitação" para que alguém com uma reputação >= `X` possa marcar como "Resolvido" e assim organizar melhor o site.

Ou existe algum problema nesse raciocínio?

Comment: Também aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1479/101

Comment: @bigown essa que você marcou como duplicada eu não havia encontrado. Obrigado pelo "norte"!